# Firestore Promises

Tags: node.js, database, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having trouble understanding this concept implementation as I am new to Firestore. I need to wait on the query before moving through the code and if the foreach condition returns two i'd love for the loop to stop. The condition should return true but instead I get false then true after the query is done

```
teamexist = (name) => {
    var exists = false;
    firebase.firestore().collection('teams').get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          if(doc.data().name === name) {
              exists = true;
              console.log(exists);
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });

    console.log("after each");

      if(!exists){
        console.log("last");
        //this.checkPlayerTeams(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
      }

    console.log(exists);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**
after each,
last,
false,
true

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**
false, true, after each

Comment: You should move code from  console.log("after each"); to console.log(exists); .   Below foreach block is  ending.

Comment: Why down vote a question I am saying I don't understand? Why would anyone ask questions if they get down-voted all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This is confusion w.r.t Event Loop in Javascript. Basically your code

```
if(!exists){
    console.log("last");
    //this.checkPlayerTeams(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
 }

console.log(exists);
```

Is Running before

```
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      if(doc.data().name === name) {
          exists = true;
          console.log(exists);
      }
   });
```

As an Async call is made to FireStore to fetch entities.

Following should work.

```
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
   if(doc.data().name === name) {
      exists = true;
      console.log(exists);
   }
   if(!exists){
    console.log("last");
    //this.checkPlayerTeams(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
 }
});
```

Comment: I could do it this way but I would want the for Each to complete when the exists = true and despite the documentation returning true does not stop the enumeration as stated in the firestore docs. Once that value is true it needs to stop looking through the other docs. Basically i want a value that comes back that states the condition was true on the inside of that foreach and then do something with the true or false value.

Answer (score 0):

I got help from somewhere else. For anyone else that is looking for the same info it was waiting on the Promise to return for a query.

```
teamexist = async (name) => {
  return firebase.firestore().collection('teams').where('name', '==', name).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      return !snapshot.empty;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      return false;
    });
}
```

this worked great and returned if what I needed existed.